# What function(s) satisifies $f(\theta)=-f(\theta+2 \pi )$?

Tags: periodic-functions

This may be a trivial question, but perhaps someone can give a detailed answer. I'm looking for a periodic function that satisfies
$$f(\theta)=-f(\theta+2\pi)$$
where $\theta$ is an angle in radians.

I have no idea if such a function exists, or how to create one. Is there any function (or class of functions) that fits this description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take
$$f(\theta)=\sin\Bigl(\frac\theta2\Bigr)\ ,$$
among others.

Alternatively, let $f(\theta)$ be anything you like for $0\le\theta<2\pi$, then define
$$f(\theta)=-f(\theta-2\pi)$$
for $2\pi<\theta<4\pi$, then
$$f(\theta)=f(\theta+4\pi)$$
for all $\theta$.

Comment: Wow. That's so simple. I can't believe I overlooked it. Thanks.